# Which process goes to which cpu socket in MPI?

Tags: process, multiprocessing, mpi, context-switch, likwid

I am running a MPI program and in my hostfile I have only one node.
The node has 2 scokets, 8 physical cores each and the hyperthreading is disabled.

`mpiexec -n 8 -f /pathtohostfile/host_file_test ./a.out`

I am using **likwid** to measure energy consumed by my program.

**Question :**

1. Are the above 8 process running on the same socket(to save energy) or processes can be randomly assigned to either socket?
2. Not sure about it, but can a process context switch to another socket?
3. In case process are randomly assigned, can I pin my process to a core/socket to measure the energy?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only one node, your 8 processes are all under control of the Linux scheduler, so, unless you use `numactl` or something to pin them down, the OS will place them for best load balancing. And it may decide to migrate them. Look into `numactl` and other "pinning" tools. `hwloc` may also do it for you.